# robots.txt disallow property

Tags: seo

I have disallowed certain pages using robots.txt for all crawlers. Do I have to write metatags for those files or web crawlers will just skip them so there is no need to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are good to go.  All of the big search engines (Google, really) obey any entries you make in `robots.txt`.  http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html

Also, be aware that the `robots.txt` file itself is viewable, so don't use this as a security measure.  http://www.cre8asiteforums.com/forums/index.php?showtopic=55546

Answer (score 2):

If the crawler you want to limit obeys robots.txt then you are fine, but if it dosn't then you are probably screwed eighterway, because chances are it will ignore meta too.

All major search-engine crawlers does obey it however so you are probably fine.

Answer (score 1):

Well written bots will ignore those pages (provided that robots.txt syntax is correct).